# PowerShell Script to Disable/Re-enable a TCP/IP Port

Tags: powershell, scripting, tcp

Is there a way to disable and re-enable a known TCP/IP port in PowerShell?

Comment: Do you mean a network adapter or a TCP port?

Comment: I would suggest using the firewall.  https://github.com/PowerShell/xNetworking#adding-a-firewall-rule is one way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make the blind assumption that you are talking about disabling & enabling TCP/IP sockets that are hosted by IIS.  (Not, say, looking for ways to block/unblock things at the Firewall level, or something else entirely.)  In that case, I happen to have the necessary scripts lying around...

```
# Get the IIsWebServer and IIsWebServerSetting WMI objects matching a display name, and combine them into one object
function Get-IIsWeb
{
    param (
        [string] $displayName = "",
        [string] $computer = "localhost"
    )

    if ($displayName -eq "")
        { $filter = "" }
    else
        { $filter = "ServerComment='$displayName'"}    

    Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsWebServerSetting" -filter $filter -computer $computer -authentication 6 | % {
        $temp = $_
        Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsWebServer" -filter "Name='$($_.Name)'" -computer $computer -authentication 6 | 
            add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name Settings -value $temp -passthru
    }
}

# Stop all websites on a given computer that are bound to the specified port, unless they are scoped to a 
# host header or IP address
function Stop-WebsiteOnPort
{
    [CmdletBinding()]    
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, valuefrompipeline=$true)]
        [int] $port,
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [string] $computer = "localhost",
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $hostName = $null,
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $ip = $null
    )

    begin { $websites = Get-IIsWeb -computer $computer }

    process
    {
        # I don't think you can do this filter in WQL
        $websites | 
          ? {
                ( $_.settings.serverbindings | ? {$_.port -eq $port -and $_.Hostname -eq $hostName -and $_.IP -eq $ip} | measure).count -gt 0
            } |
          % {
                $_.stop()
            }               
    }
}
```

The actual WMI code to re-enable a site is pretty much identical to the code for stopping one seen above.  However, you'll need to do a little more work: there could be arbitrarily many sites configured to use a given port, but only 1 can run at a time.  Either you'll need an additional parameter from the user, or some heuristic for picking the "right" site.

Comment: On second look, I don't think its what I need.  Here's what's happening:  We have an OLAP tool called TM1 that runs on a server and allows users to connect via a client tool on port 12345.  The cubes on the server are updated daily, but are slowed waaay down by users trying to connect and calculate.  I would like to block them from connecting while the update is happening, then allow them once the update is finished.  The service has to be running in order for the update to happen.

Comment: You'll have to either (a) consult the TM1 documentation and hope they have a programmatic way to toggle connectivity without bringing down the service (b) block the users at the network layer, i.e. use a Firewall or IPSEC or similar.